# How do I indicate a lifetime bound on a type parameter when using generic associated types?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime, generic-associated-types

I am trying to implement a trait with a generic associated type for a struct with a generic type. I'm using nightly version `1.47.0-nightly (2020-07-20 f9a3086363f214f2b56b)`.

I have structs `S1` and `S2`, a trait with a GAT, and an implementation:

```rust
#![allow(incomplete_features)]
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

use core::marker::PhantomData;

struct S1<T>(PhantomData<T>);
struct S2<'a, T: 'a>(PhantomData<(T, &'a ())>);

trait MyTrait {
    type A<'a>;
}

impl MyTrait for S1<f64> {
    type A<'a> = S2<'a, f64>;
}
```

This works, but I want to implement the trait for a generic `T`:

```rust
impl<T> MyTrait for S1<T> {
    type A<'a> = S2<'a, T>;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ce47ed615dbfdebaba9c616b5357d81)

I now need to indicate that `T` lives as long as `'a`, as is required by the definition of `S2`:

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:14:5
   |
13 | impl<T> MyTrait for S1<T> {
   |      - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'a`
14 |     type A<'a> = S2<'a, T>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

How can this be done?

I found [Generic associated type may not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62316153/generic-associated-type-may-not-live-long-enough), but it might be outdated as it claims that the code is not yet implemented. But then, why does complex code like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=564ad1daecd9b8a4fce6fa93d28fb0dd) compile (and work as expected)?

Comment: What could the potential downsides of adding a `T: 'static` bound be?

Comment: If `T` lives as long as `'a`, _for any possible_ `'a`, then `T: 'static`.

Answer (score 1):

```
impl<T> MyTrait for S1<T> {
    type A<'a> = S2<'a, T>;
}
```

`T` is fixed for the entire implementation, and that includes its lifetime. However, the lifetime `'a` can vary at the point it is used. If you need the lifetime of `T` to be longer than `'a` then this has to be true for all possible lifetimes. Without changing something else in that implementation, the only lifetime that `T` can have is therefore `'static`:

```
impl<T: 'static> MyTrait for S1<T> {
    type A<'a> = S2<'a, T>;
}
```

That is, `T` cannot contain any references apart from references to static variables.

Please also bear in mind that GATs are not yet stabilised and the feature is likely still incomplete. It's at the stage where you can play around with it to get a feel for what it can do, but not ready for the real world yet.